# HTML5 canvas video with React

Tags: javascript, html5, react.js

I'm trying to work HTML5 canvas video into a React application while making the code as clean as possible. What kind of improvements should be made to improve the performance utilizing the React to its fullest potential?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import video from './video.mp4';
import watermark from './watermark.png';

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
}

componentDidMount() {

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 1280;
canvas.height = 720;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(document.querySelector('video'), 0, 0, 720, 1280);
                    context.drawImage(
                        document.querySelector('.watermark'),
                        parseInt(document.querySelector('select').value),
                        parseInt(document.querySelector('select').value)
                    );
                    if (document.querySelector('input[name=live]').checked) {
                        this.setState({ image: canvas.toDataURL() });
                    }               

}


render() {
    const range = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1280; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }

    return (
        <div className="app"> 

            <video  src={video} controls />

            <div>
            <div className="watermarkButton" style={{}}>

                <span className="watermarkButtonX">Watermark X
                <select className="positionX">
                    {range.map(i => (
                        <option key={i}>{i}</option>
                    ))} </select></span>

                <span className="watermarkButtonY">Watermark Y
                <select className="positionY">
                    {range.map(i => (
                        <option key={i}>{i}</option>
                    ))} </select></span>



                <span>Live</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="live" />
                </div>


                <button className = "watermarkButton watermarkSubmit"
                    onClick={() => {
                        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.width = 1280;
                        canvas.height = 720;
                        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        context.drawImage(document.querySelector('video'), 0, 0, 1280, 720);
                        context.drawImage(
                            document.querySelector('.watermark'),
                            parseInt(document.querySelector('.positionX').value),
                            parseInt(document.querySelector('.positionY').value)
                        );
                        this.setState({ image: canvas.toDataURL() });
                    }}> Watermark! </button>


                <img alt="watermarks" className="watermark" src={watermark} style={{ visibility: 'visible' }}  />
                <img alt="watermarks"   className="imageDisplay" height="405px" width="560px" src={this.state.image} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
                }

            }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

**For loop inside `Render()`**

The loop gets called each time the component re-renders, it's a `1280` pushes to an array and that can be a performance issue, you can set it in `componentDidMount` or even outside the class since it's not dependent on its data,

Consider [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create and fill the array without creating an intermediate one.

```
const range = Array.from({length: 1280}, (_, i) => i);
```

And since you're filling it with `int`s and the `select` value is an `int` you don't really need `parseInt`.

**Using `document.querySelector` to read values**

> Basically, you can't easily rely on the input field because the state needs to come from
>   the React app's state, not from the browser's idea of what the value should be.

See more explanation in [this blog post](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/onchange-in-reactjs).

You should instead use the state to store the values of the inputs. ( see code snippet below )

**Accessing the DOM using `document.querySelector`**

> In React, we do not directly manipulate the actual DOM. Instead, we must manipulate the virtual representation and let React take care of changing the browser's DOM.

Check [this article](https://www.fullstackreact.com/p/jsx-and-the-virtual-dom/) for in depth explanation and the [different ways to access the DOM](https://davidwalsh.name/get-react-component-element).

Using `refs`, instead of doing `document.querySelector('video')`, you can add a `ref` like : `<video src={video} controls ref={video => this.video = video}/>` then use `this.video` to do what you would do with a regular html element.

[Using html5 canvas with react](https://blog.cloudboost.io/using-html5-canvas-with-react-ff7d93f5dc76)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import video from './video.mp4';
import watermark from './watermark.png';

const range = Array.from({ length: 1280 }, (_, i) => i);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      select: 0,
      live: false,
      positionX: 0,
      positionY: 0,
      checked: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const context = this.canvas1.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 720, 1280);
    context.drawImage(this.watermark, this.state.select, this.state.select);

    if (this.state.live) {
      this.setState({ image: canvas.toDataURL() });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <video src={video} controls ref={video => this.video = video} />
        <div>
          <div className="watermarkButton" style={{}}>

            <span className="watermarkButtonX">Watermark X
              <select
                className="positionX"
                onChange={value => this.setState({ select: value, positionX: value })}
                value={this.state.positionX}>
                {range.map(i => (
                  <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </span>

            <span className="watermarkButtonY">Watermark Y
              <select
                className="positionY"
                onChange={value => this.setState({ select: value, positionY: value })}
                value={this.state.positionY}>
                >
                {range.map(i => (
                  <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </span>

            <span>Live</span>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="live"
              checked={this.state.live}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ live: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>


          <button className="watermarkButton watermarkSubmit"
            onClick={() => {
              const context = this.canvas2.getContext('2d');
              context.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
              context.drawImage(this.watermark, this.state.positionX, this.state.positionY);
              this.setState({ image: canvas.toDataURL() });
            }}> Watermark! </button>

          <canvas ref={canvas => this.canvas1 = canvas} width={1280} height={720} />
          <canvas ref={canvas => this.canvas2 = canvas} width={1280} height={720} />

          <img
            alt="watermarks"
            className="watermark"
            src={watermark}
            style={{ visibility: 'visible' }}
            ref={watermark => this.watermark = watermark}
          />
          <img
            alt="watermarks"
            className="imageDisplay"
            height="405px"
            width="560px"
            src={this.state.image}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```